# ExceptionInInitializerError when cassandra unit tests runs on Jenkins but works locally

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, cassandra

Cassandra unit tests works locally but not on jenkins.

edit: I have multiple poms and if i run clean package on the whole project i get the same error. Is this due to different target maps? 1 cassandra.yaml is in test-classes, one in embeddedCassandra and one in the target folder at the bottom of the project in another embedded cassandra folder.

starting cassandra with cu-cassandra.yaml result in the same error.

The cassandra yaml file is located in resources

```
System.setProperty("cassandra.config", yamlUrl);
EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra("cassandra.yaml");


java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.getStorageConfigURL(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:80)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.<clinit>(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:94)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:125)
    at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.mkdirs(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:349)
    at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.cleanupAndLeaveDirs(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:321)
    at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:122)
    at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:91)
    at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:70)
    at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:66)
    at com.something.connector.HttpConnectorTest.beforeTest(HttpConnectorTest.java:59)
```

Comment: There must be more logs for this exception. Can you add those too?

Comment: That is all i get from jenkins build

Comment: Can you print what is the YAML URL before setting the system property

Comment: file://C:/repos/connector/http/target/test/test-classes/cassandra.yaml.

Comment: I have tried / // /// after file. and set the url to the yaml in embeddedCassandra folder

Comment: Also tried starting with the default cu-cassandra.yaml, works locally but not on jenkins

Comment: I have multiple poms, i get it also when i run clean package on the whole project. Is there a way to choose target map?

Comment: Is your Jenkins also windows system because the path you mentioned is windows. If yes, try replacing file://C:/repos/connector/http/target/test/test-classes/cassandra.yaml. with file://C:\repos\connector\http\target\test\test-classes\cassandra.yaml.

Comment: variable is not hardcoded it will change / to \ if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me setting tmp folder that is not the default and set cassandra.config

```
String folderPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        String path = folderPath + fileSeparator + "target" + fileSeparator + "httpconnector" + fileSeparator
                + "embeddedCassandra";
        URL url = HttpConnectorTest.class.getResource("/cassandra.yaml");
        System.setProperty("cassandra.config", url.toString());

    try {
        EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra("cassandra.yaml", path, 100000);
```